# Why flutter pdf setPage is not working if set the value return from AlertDialog in android only?

Tags: flutter

My code is view the pdf using by flutter_pdfview from online url. Opening the pdf is no issue. So I wrote the pagination at floatingActionButton. There is "Previous", "Page / Total Page" and "Next". If click page button, Alert Dialog box pop up and user can enter the page and can go to specified page. It is working on iOS. But at Android, after enter the page number on Dialog and click "Move" button and then dialog return the entered value and set the page number at

```
await snapshot.data!.setPage(pageNumber - 1);
```

But it is not call the PDFView's onPageChanged. If I don't call the dialog and just simply call snapshot.data!.setPage(pageNumber - 1), it is working.
I think something wrong with dialog.

May I know why it is only happening on android and only happening if set the page number return from dialog?

First Pdf page

[image: First Pdf page]

Dialog to enter page number
[image: Dialog to enter page number]

Full source code

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter_pdfview/flutter_pdfview.dart';
import 'package:auto_size_text/auto_size_text.dart';
import 'package:thitsarparami/helper/enum.dart';
import 'package:thitsarparami/widgets/circular_progress_indicator_widget.dart';

class PdfView extends StatefulWidget {
  final String url;
  final LoadPDF loadPDF;
  final String title;
  const PdfView(
      {Key? key, required this.title, required this.url, required this.loadPDF})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<PdfView> createState() => _PdfViewerState();
}

class _PdfViewerState extends State<PdfView> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  String? path;
  bool _isLoading = true;
  TextEditingController? textController;

  final Completer<PDFViewController> _controller =
  Completer<PDFViewController>();
  int? pages = 0;
  int? currentPage = 0;
  bool isReady = false;
  String errorMessage = '';
  bool isButtonActive = false;

  loadDocument() async {
    String fileName = widget.url.split("/").last;
    switch (widget.loadPDF) {
      case LoadPDF.assets:
        fromAsset(widget.url, fileName).then((f) {
          setState(() {
            path = f.path;
            _isLoading = false;
           });
        });
        break;
      case LoadPDF.url:
        createFileOfPdfUrl().then((f) {
          setState(() {
            path = f.path;
            _isLoading = false;
          });
        });
        break;
      case LoadPDF.file:
        File file = File(widget.url);
         setState(() {
           path = file.path;
          _isLoading = false;
        });
        break;
    }
  }

  Future<File> createFileOfPdfUrl() async {
Completer<File> completer = Completer();
//print("Start download file from internet!");
try {
  final url = widget.url;
  final filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
  var request = await HttpClient().getUrl(Uri.parse(url));
  var response = await request.close();
  var bytes = await consolidateHttpClientResponseBytes(response);
  var dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  //print("Download files");
  //print("${dir.path}/$filename");
  File file = File("${dir.path}/$filename");

  await file.writeAsBytes(bytes, flush: true);
  completer.complete(file);
} catch (e) {
  throw Exception('Error parsing asset file!');
}

return completer.future;
   }

 Future<File> fromAsset(String asset, String filename) async {
// To open from assets, you can copy them to the app storage folder, and the access them "locally"
Completer<File> completer = Completer();

try {
  var dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  File file = File("${dir.path}/$filename");
  var data = await rootBundle.load(asset);
  var bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List();
  await file.writeAsBytes(bytes, flush: true);
  completer.complete(file);
} catch (e) {
  throw Exception('Error parsing asset file!');
}

    return completer.future;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadDocument();
    textController = TextEditingController();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    textController?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
        elevation: 0,
        title: AutoSizeText(
          widget.title,
          style: Theme.of(context).appBarTheme.titleTextStyle,
        ),
        leading: IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.arrow_back,
            color: Theme.of(context).primaryIconTheme.color!,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: _isLoading
        ? const CircularProgressIndicatorWidget()
        : PDFView(
            filePath: path,
            enableSwipe: true,
            swipeHorizontal: false,
            autoSpacing: false,
            pageFling: true,
            pageSnap: true,
            defaultPage: currentPage!,
            fitPolicy: FitPolicy.BOTH,
            preventLinkNavigation:
                false, // if set to true the link is handled in flutter
            onRender: (_pages) {
              setState(() {
                pages = _pages;
                isReady = true;
              });
            },
            onError: (error) {
              setState(() {
                errorMessage = error.toString();
              });
              //print(error.toString());
            },
            onPageError: (page, error) {
              setState(() {
                errorMessage = '$page: ${error.toString()}';
              });
              //print('$page: ${error.toString()}');
            },
            onViewCreated: (PDFViewController pdfViewController) {
              _controller.complete(pdfViewController);
            },
            onLinkHandler: (String? uri) {
              //print('goto uri: $uri');
            },
            onPageChanged: (int? page, int? total) {
              //print('page change: $page/$total');
              setState(
                () {
                  currentPage = page;
                },
              );
            },
          ),
  ),
  floatingActionButton: FutureBuilder<PDFViewController>(
    future: _controller.future,
    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<PDFViewController> snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return FloatingActionButton.extended(
          label: Row(
            children: [
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.navigate_before,
                    color: (currentPage! > 0) ? Colors.white : Colors.grey),
                onPressed: (currentPage! < pages!)
                    ? () async {
                        await snapshot.data!.setPage(currentPage! - 1);
                      }
                    : null,
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  elevation: 0,
                  side: const BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  minimumSize: Size.zero,
                  tapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
                ),
                onPressed: () async {
                  final result = await openDialog();
                  if (result == null || result.isEmpty) return;
                  int pageNumber = int.parse(result);
                  await snapshot.data!.setPage(pageNumber - 1);
                },
                child: Text("${currentPage! + 1}"),
              ),
              Text(" / $pages"),
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.navigate_next,
                    color: (currentPage! + 1 < pages!)
                        ? Colors.white
                        : Colors.grey),
                onPressed: (currentPage! < pages!)
                    ? () async {
                        await snapshot.data!.setPage(currentPage! + 1);
                      }
                    : null,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          onPressed: null,
        );
      }
      return Container();
    },
  ),
);
  }

  Future<String?> openDialog() => showDialog<String>(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) => StatefulBuilder(
      builder: (context, setState) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: const Text('Go to page'),
          content: TextField(
            autofocus: true,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Page number'),
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
              FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
            ],
            controller: textController,
            onChanged: (value) {
              if (value.isNotEmpty) {
                int pageNumber = int.parse(value);
                setState(() {
                  isButtonActive = pageNumber < pages!;
                });
              }
            },
            onSubmitted: (_) => gotToPage(),
          ),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                textController?.clear();
              },
              child: const Text('Cancel'),
            ),
            TextButton(
              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                  onSurface: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
              onPressed: isButtonActive
                  ? () {
                      gotToPage();
                      textController?.clear();
                    }
                  : null,
              child: const Text('Move'),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    ),
  );

  void gotToPage() {
    Navigator.of(context).pop(textController?.text);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why this error occurred in android. It is happening because opening the keyboard. So Now I am using number picker and it is working now.